# On Number Theory and Goldbach's Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Good day. My question is: Does every even number have the form $n=p+ 2+q$, or $n=p- 2+q$ with $p, q $ prime numbers, such that $p\pm2$ is prime number? Up to $n = 1000$ I know that it is true, and it isn't equivalent to goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Well, we know every even number up to $4\times 10^{18}$ can be written as $p+q$ (and we think every even number above $4$ can be)... which implies the same of your question. I don't *think* the answer to your question is known - it seems stronger than any known results on Goldbach's conjecture - but I'm not totally sure of that.

Comment: This problem has been changed into a new problem since it was first posted. Now, if $p$ is a prime and $p \pm 2$ must be prime---if your original conjecture were true with this added hypothesis---would we not then have to have an infinitude of twin primes, which is certainly an unresolved problem?

Comment: What kind of answers are you expecting? This question is like asking us to prove Goldbach and Twin Prime at the same time.

Comment: It is not even clear formulated whether $p\pm 2$ must both be prime or only one of them. But as mentioned in several comments, this question is out of reach because it is more difficult than two very famous unsolved problems.

Comment: Just to state the question concisely, OP in effect asks (assuming Goldbach and twin prime conjectures are both true): Is it true that every even number can be partitioned into two prime addends with the further requirement that (at least) one of the addends is a member of a twin prime pair?

Answer (score 2):

(1) With the new hypothesis that you added that $p \pm 2$ must be a prime, your conjecture reduces to Goldbach's Conjecture. Do you see why? (and ignoring the fact that it presupposes an infinitude of twin primes.)

(2)  If you remove this new hypothesis and leave the problem as you originally stated it, then you would also have the following theorem: "My conjecture is true if and only if Goldbach's Conjecture is true.'' And the reason for this is as follows: Since Goldbach's Conjecture is true, as a commentator pointed out earlier, for every even number up to $4 x 10^{18}$, then choose an even number $n$; then, say, subtract 2 from it. It will be a number which satisfies Goldbach's Conjecture. Thus, take a pair of primes $p, q$ satisfying Goldbach's Conjecture (there may be more than one such pair) whose sum is $n - 2$, and then add 2. This gets you back to your $n$. A similar argument follows if you choose an even number $n$ and then add 2 it.

So, I guess it could be said that your original conjecture is true for all even numbers up to $4 x 10^{18} - 2.$

Comment: yes, but goldbach conjecture no implies my question. For example in goldbach conjecture $4=(0+2)+2=(4-2)+2$, my question begin from $6=(5-2)+3$.

Comment: Goldbach's conjecture in modern form Also starts at 6 or above. You can even make a geometric construction of a Goldbach  Conjecture form based in Cartesian coordinates. What does your conjecture imply geometrically?

Comment: Goldbach conjecture does not explicitly tell us about the addends.

Comment: horse manure. $$2n=p+q\implies n+n=p+q\implies n-p=q-n$$

Comment: that merits the fields medal... I mean the sum expressed as indicated by my question.